# UDP behavior goes wrong when using two identical scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

I attached two of the following scripts to a single GameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    static UdpClient udp;
    private string udp_message = "";
    Thread thread;
    public int port = 8888;

    void Start()
    {
        udp = new UdpClient(port);

        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        thread.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        string port_string = port.ToString();
        Debug.Log(port_string + ":" + udp_message);
    }

    void ThreadMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = null;
                byte[] data = udp.Receive(ref remoteEP);
                udp_message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I used 8888 as the port for one script, as shown in the following image. The other script used port 8889.

[image]

I am using two different ports on 8888 and 8889.

However, when I send data to only the 8888 port, the UDP on the 8889 port also seems to be responding.

What is the cause of this?

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you set the `public int port = 8888;` to `public int port = -1;`. Are you receiving an error? Are you sure the 8889 is used in the `Start` method?

Comment: I used `public int port = -1;` and there was no error and as before I just sent data to port 8888 and both ports 8888 and 8899 responded.I ran `Debug.Log (port)` inside the Start method, but when I started the game both 8888 and 8899 were printed. It seems that port 8899 is definitely being used.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen this doesn't matter afterwards since the serialized values in the Inspector overrule any later change in code (the values in code are just the default values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your `udp` field is [**`static`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)!

Both instances of your component overwrite it with different references in

```
udp = new UdpClient(port);
```

So basically whichever script runs last "wins" and you are only ever using that `UdpClient` instance.

Later both your threads will access the very same `udp` reference for doing

```
udp.Receive(...);
```

Simply do not make you field `static` and you should be fine ^^

```
private UdpClient udp;
```

---

And to your empty `catch` block ... I would at least make it

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.LogException(e);
}
```

which displays an error in the console but doesn't interrupt the thread.

---

And then also make sure to clean up!

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    thread?.Abort();
    udp?.Dispose();
}
```

otherwise you might end up with zomby threads or blocked UDP ports ;)

Comment: I figured you would be right. I overlooked the fact that the udp and thread variables are not private. And I tried changing them to private, but still the problem persisted. There may be something else causing the problem. Do you think it is possible that they are not resolved because the port number is public?

Comment: @taichi this has absolutely nothing to do with `private` or not (in fact in `c#` by default if you don't say otherwise they already **are** `private` anyway) ... this is about your `udp` being **`static`** ... remove that `static`!

Comment: Great! It solved.Thanks.